# Custom TextFieldTableCell in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I want create custom TextFieldTableCell, that repeat behavior cell TextFieldTableCell, but allow replace Context Menu at child element **TextField**. I writed cell factory:

```
tableColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TableData, Double>, TableCell<TableData, Double>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<TableData, Double> call(TableColumn<TableData, Double> param) {
                var tc = new TextFieldTableCell<TableData, Double>(new CustomDoubleStringConverter());
                var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                var itemsMenu = TextFieldContextMenuCreator.createDefaultMenuItemsTextField((TextField)tc.getGraphic(), resources);
                contextMenu.getItems().addAll(itemsMenu);
                ((TextField)tc.getGraphic()).setContextMenu(contextMenu);

                return tc;
            }
        });
```

But, method `getGraphics()` always return `null`. How this make?

Comment: the graphic is only set on the cell's first editing (see the sources) - the grab it after it's available, install a one-time listener on the graphicProperty (that is install it and let it remove itself when you have the graphic)

Comment: @kleopatra Ovation. There are sources! You can frame this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By advice [kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra) I create custom textfield cell class, with help the sources JavaFX. It in I use internal TextField, and during his creation I create necessary Context menu for him.